Book(s) recomendation for Probability Theory Foundations
I am in the process of learning ML and AI. I've been taking some courses, and I now understand the foundations of the big picture of Machine Learning. I've been using Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning as my go-to-book.
After a few reads of the chapters I've covered so far, I think I understand the general concepts in each of the methodologies, BUT I do recognize that my probability foundations are weak, therefore I want to improve that: Are there any recommendations on (good) books about probability theory that I could benefit from?
*(good) : by good I mean a book that gives you not only the theory and practice exercises, but especially a book that provides you with the Intuition and practical meaning of the topic being taught; I believe that is why I love Bishop's book because he tries to explain what the equations mean, what the concept implies, and what in practice is used. I looking for the same but on probability theory.
More specifically, I found that I could not completely grasp the Bayesian framework. I would want to go over it in a probability book. I believe it doesn't hurt from the foundations all the way to the full Bayesian framework theory. by the way, if there are any compilations of topics on which I should focus, it would be highly appreciated as well.
Thanks in advance,
Cheers

well bishop just published a new book, though it's not strictly on prob theory, and depends what you want to learn about probability theory

Thanks, I did notice his new Deep Learning book. It’s definitely in queue for reading… thanks!

This right here is the money shot.
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2022/pages/classes-reading-and-in-class-materials/
That's essentially what you're looking for. They get into Bayesian Inferences at Unit 2. This is better than a textbook, it has courses, lectures, problem sets, and if you're ever confused just ask a LLM for an  answer; and yes it has a textbook inside of it too.

This is just an amazing material! As you mentioned, just what I’m looking for !
Thanks for the recommendation, this definitely answers my question. Thanks Joseph

of course! Always happy to help :D
